# Why will my fetch API call map one nested objects, but not the other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, fetch-api

I'm parsing data from the NASA API using React, and for some reason I can map one nested object within the return but not the other.

Here is my parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './NasaAPI.scss'
import NasaImages from './NasaImages'

const NasaAPI = () => {
    const [nasaData, setNasaData] = useState([])
    const [nasaImage, setNasaImage] = useState("")
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const fetchData = async (e) => {
        const data = await fetch(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${searchInput}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setNasaData(data.collection.items))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .finally(setLoading(false))
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        fetchData()
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSearchInput(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Search NASA Images</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input name="searchValue" type="text" value={searchInput} onChange={handleChange}></input>
                <button value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <section>
                <NasaImages nasaData={nasaData} loading={loading}/>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NasaAPI
```

Here's where the issue is, in the child component:

```
import React from 'react'

const NasaImages = ({ nasaData }) => {
    console.log(nasaData)

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>This is a where the data go. </h2>
            {
                nasaData && nasaData.map((data, idx) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={idx}>
                            <p>{data.href}</p>
                            <div>
                                {/* {data.links.map((data) => {
                                    return <p>{data.href}</p>
                                })} */}
                                {data.data.map((data) => {
                                    return <p>{data.description}</p>
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default NasaImages
```

The current configuration works, and will display a `data.description` (`data.data.map`) mapping property. However, I want the commented code immediately above it to work which displays a `data.href` (`data.links.map`) property.

The JSON looks as follows:

[image: some code]

So, the issue is that I can map one set of properties, `data.data.map`, but cannot access the other in the same object, `data.links.map`, without getting the error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists a `data` element sans a `links` property, in other words there is some undefined `data.links` property and you can't map that. Use Optional Chaining operator on `data.links` when mapping, i.e. `data.links?.map`. Use this on any potentially undefined nested properties.

```
const NasaImages = ({ nasaData = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>This is a where the data go. </h2>
      {nasaData.map((data, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <p>{data.href}</p>
          <div>
            {data.links?.map((data, i) => <p key={i}>{data.href}</p>)}
            {data.data?.map((data, i) => <p key={i}>{data.description}</p>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Would that be something I'd check for next time, or would this just be a default case to look for when parsing JSON data? Again, thanks!

Comment: @Chris It's generally a good idea to write defensive code, even if the data contract says the properties would/should be available. Whether you do this when consuming received data, or if you use null-checks in the UI like this, or both, is up to you and specific use-cases.